How many people could we get off of the planet in a month?
On August 19th, 2024, a rogue black hole passes through our solar system, flinging a 200km diameter chunk of rock at the Earth, to impact in 30 days! Earth is doomed!
But all hope is not lost. The Golgadexians, those aliens that have been punking us for centuries, have told us that they can send a rescue craft large enough for our entire species. The caveat being that, even with their amazing technology, it'll take a year to get here.
How many humans can we save?
Note: This is, I think, a simplified version of CasualWorldBuilder's question about us saving the Venusians.

In what level of detail do you want to know that answer? +/- 1000 or +/-1? Globally all nations or just USA? Also civilians or only those who are currently in some astronauts training (maybe also jet pilots)? Do presidents take precedence? Are space stations supposed to be safe? Because 200km is quite a number.

Ok, estimated ejecta spread is about 250km for some "default" assumptions. Probably the space stations are safe (alt. 350-400km). Given they have enough supplies for air, food, water, waste, etc. for 1 year without resupply.

@Antares, give me an order of magnitude

Okay, then it is what Slarty said. Certainly below 100.

Hopefully the space stations are at the far side of the planet at impact, @Antares, or the fireball will irradiate them, ejecta notwithstanding.

@jdunlop: What is the basis for that assumption? Because I think, a fireball cannot get that much further into space than the atmosphere providing the oxygen for a burn/explosion (~100km). Ejecta like smoke etc. can reach higher altitudes. But sure, far side would certainly be beneficial. And might be even achieved by burning some fuel.

@Antares Infrared radiation from the fireball...

None - there's no way the ISS could survive the ejecta from such an event, and there's no other craft that could provide life support for a year.

@Antares - simulations (https://www.hou.usra.edu/meetings/metsoc2017/pdf/6132.pdf) have suggested thermal flux could melt rock at a distance of several hundred km from a 3km diameter impactor.  With a 200km impactor, the thermal flux via infrared and even the visible light from the fireball would put enormous thermal stress on anything on the same side of the planet.  The Chicxulub impactor, substantially smaller than the proposed impactor, would have caused thermal damage anywhere within sixteen thousand km of the fireball, provided line of sight.

@jdunlop: I think there is some misconception involved. The paper talks about the effects of the impact on earth, meaning inside the atmosphere. This leads to melted rock etc. -- The ISS is subject to constant radiation from the sun and the earth, but still largely unaffected. There is no atmosphere to transport the heat. The ISS is also just a "small" target (silhouette), the majority of radiation will just pass by. My opinion, I might be wrong. See thermosphere and heat vs. temperature in space: https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/5n8brf/can_someone_explain_the_thermosphere/

@Antares - the paper notes that thermal flux precedes blast effects, and notes that atmosphere is transparent to thermal radiation.  This is not something mediated by an atmosphere, it's infrared radiation travelling at light speed.  (Also, at 200km, a teratonne detonation has three thousand times the apparent brightness of the sun, so "constant radiation from the sun and the earth" is small beer in comparison.)

Part 1) The question isn't how many people I can get into orbit, its how many nuclear missiles! The problem being that even if you got people into orbit there's nowhere to put them for the 11 months its going to take the rescue ship to arrive & not enough food air & water to keep them alive for that long. You have the ISS and Chinese space station that's it! and both are on LEO. So they're both toast when the meteor (as described) hits.

Part 2) So you either tell the aliens to send something a lot smaller bit much quicker so that some % of the population can be saved (and P.S 'Thanks for not warning us about the approaching black hole arseholes,!' Way to go." Or as a fall back position try to Bruce Willis the rock down to something survivable (or both).

@jdunlop I wonder if the thermal impact from a 200km asteroid at "medium velocity" (~40 km/s, less than required to escape solar system expected) would be enough to vaporize oceans. If not, a submarine located somewhere off the main impact vector might survive both the impact and a year afterwards.

@Vesper It'd take a lot of energy (10*27 joules) to boil the oceans.  But the submarine would have to be very specialized.  Chicxulub was a twentieth the size of this monster, and geologic strata make it clear that tsunamis a kilometre high swept across the oceans and land.  Normal submarine crush depths wouldn't get the submarine to safety unless it had most of the Earth between it and the impact and was in the right spot.

@jdunlop for a sub, it's enough to be in the middle of the ocean and not be where the rock strikes, then it'll be as good as riding a wave, nothing else. I was wondering if the impact would leave no liquid water to stay in, as a sub on the ground would be lost to earthquakes, and a 200-km wide rock might carry enough, depending on speed (mass of 1e19 kg, and 8 orders for speed makes enough), but from the looks of it a sub would get cooked even if the oceans won't boil, as it's not designed to have its inhabited part cooled against outside water.

@Boat: It is not. Therefore my question. But still, USA is a natural conclusion because of their launch capabilities which would give high chances of getting off the planet in this scenario. I strongly advocate for considering the other nations too and I am a huge fan of any space program, but sadly there is not much known about their capabilities. At least not without digging into it more. And also I am not located in the US, just to address the hidden sidestab there. This topic has nothing to do with race, nation or other stuff of that notion. Keep it to yourself please.

@Vesper according to Sleep et al. (1989) (probably paywalled if you're not at a university), a 190km impactor would evaporate the photic zone, i.e. the top 200m of the oceans. I imagine this would make the rest of the water rather hot, so a submarine would need to be in the very deep ocean to stand a chance. It would also cause the atmosphere to expand, de-orbiting any space stations that somehow avoided the ejecta. So maybe a deep ocean submarine is the only possible chance.

Do you want to save humans, or humanity? If the Golgadexians are really interested in preserving humanity, then the trick is to send a cryogenic chamber into space with billions of frozen embryos and sperm, along with storage media that contains massive amounts of data on human history and development. Existing humans would be wiped out, but our civilization and humanity itself could live on. With a concerted effort, this could be arranged in 30 days, as there would be no need to worry about a specific trajectory or launch window. Just get the ship 'up there'.

@jdunlop -- No worries! The space station will swing around to the ejecta field in about an hour!

@N.Virgo this news is actually good. Photic zone is relatively small, and we all know that the deep ocean has 4C temperature due to water having the most density at it. Assuming the impact zone is far from the sub, the atmosphere being superheated, the water starting to boil from the top (if a core breach happened under the sub, it can move away), the water would eventually segregate by temperature, and the lower levels of ocean would not heat too much to cook the sub even at 600m depth (past boiling-up of top layers). And there are enough subs to host a thousand people already.

@Vesper that makes sense. One or other of us should probably post an answer with this information.

Not enough to bother
There is something like 5 types of currently operational space craft - all with crew sizes in the single digits.
At most you are getting 15-20 people into space per launch.
Where do they go - you might put them on the Space Station, but you have another problem - supplies and logistics - if the earth is wiped out, they have to sustain a year before help arrives.
Assuming perfect weather for the month - 8 hour round trip to get up to the space station and back to earth, another 8 hours for turnaround etc (which is being massively optimistic). You have approximately 90 - 8 hour windows, alternating gives you about 45 launch windows. Best case scenario - maybe 1,000 people.
Realistically though - given the constraints of the space station and supplies - I would say you would be lucky to get 100 people. And even that number is wildly optimistic.
The best option therefore would be to try to attack the asteroid or deflect it

At T-30d to impact, attacking or deflecting a 200km (diameter, I assume) chunk of rock isn't going to happen.

@jdunlop - probably - but I would rather go out shooting than trying to run away - feels better :D

I just did the calculations - all 2,500 Mt TNT's worth of our nuclear weapons, launched in sequence and detonated simultaneously, would deliver around 0.01% of the binding energy that I estimated for an asteroid of that size. Definitely not gonna work.

@controlgroup - a 0.01 percent chance of success - in the face of total annihilation, sounds like a good shot to me.

No, 0.01% of the binding energy means a chance of success that rounds to 0% (it means you can't blow up the asteroid at all). Of course, what you could do in such a scenario is to use them all up on one side of the asteroid to deflect it by outgassing. But again, you would need to launch all the world's nukes and you'd need to get them all there safely and have them detonate simultaneously - that would be more like a 95% chance of success if we could do all those things. Just push it hard enough that it misses; the Earth is a very small target in a very large void. (+1 from me.)

@controlgroup - Noted. I hereby appoint you to be in charge of shooting asteroids in space if ever one comes close :)

Bruce Willis is proud of ya, @controlgroup

If we select a thousand or even a million people to be saved, will the other eight billion calmly let it happen?

You don't take 100 people. You take 100 people + frozen sperm and eggs from thousands more.

@WGroleau No.  They especially won't let the disabled billionaire who funded the project go.  But at the last minute a speech from a guy will talk down the angry mob by pointing out that any of them successful at displacing anybody already on the space craft will themselves be displaced by the next wave...

@Michael, I'm not so sure.  Have you seen all the images on TV of people in Afghanistan who thought they could hang on to the outside of a plane in flight?

can you detail your launch window calculation? what prevents launching rockets one after another (assuming we have several vehicles available), and from multiple launch pads?

@njzk2 - that was launching all 5 at the same time....

I don't accept "not enough to bother." People won't care whether or not it'll work. They'll try anything for survival.

@controlgroup why do you say "simultaneously" detonating nukes to try and deflect it? Sequentially would provide the same impulse (so long as they're not close enough to damage each other)

@ChrisH because simultaneously is faster. Of course in-sequence would be functionally the same, but if you’re going for speed… (There are much better ways to do what I’m talking about, I know, but it’s fun to talk about detonating a lot of nukes at the same time.)

@controlgroup I think you'd want to do them sequentially, with enough space between each nuke that one rogue nuke doesn't wipe out the entire crowd.

Yeah that’s in reality the best way to go. It’s less fun to say “using a lot of nukes in sequence” than “use a bunch of nukes at the same time” though.

@RobertRapplean - the number you would save would not be enough to continue the human population, without massive in-breeding issues. Using the launch craft to deliver a nuclear payload to the asteroid to push it off by a fraction of a percent is more likely to work. Of course, if you change 1 month to 6 months, things get more interesting

No people but maybe the whole human race.
Sustaining human life for a year in space requires food, water and air, which in 30 days to get ready, is basically impossible to save enough people to actually make a difference.
The solution is to store our knowledge, history, art, science, music, etc digitally and then send frozen eggs and sperm in well shielded storage containers.
All the existing humans might die but the human race would have a chance to live on

You would need a method to grow those frozen gametes into people, right? From a species survival point of view, would it make sense to send as many young female IVF specialists and obstetricians as you can, along with your archive of knowledge and culture?

It would but time is the enemy there isn't time to send many more people as the few ships that can be made ready in time must be packed with food and supplies so those aboard the stations can survive for a year. But if there is room for anyone then  young female IVF specialists would be good.

@craq The whole point is we're getting picked up by an alien race with amazing technology. They would have the raw materials plus everything we know medically so they should be able to figure it out. Once you start trying to save actual people, you need food, water, air, heat for an entire year and everything is exponentially harder.

@craq it's a last ditch effort time capsule - The expectation isn't for humans to open it and reseed the human race, the expectation is someday some species will happen to come across it and be curious enough to grow a human, reseeding the race.
The odds probably are practically zero, but its better than sitting there and doing nothing I suppose

The Golgadexians might actually go for that. If they're willing to flash-build an 8 billion person rescue craft and launch it untold lightyears, they might be willing to set up an artificial habitat and regrow humanity.

ObSF: The Genesis Quest by Donald Moffitt (1986).  Aliens in another galaxy pick up the human broadcast of our entire genome and culture, and they build humans and help them reconstruct a culture.

@craq, why do the obstetricians and IVF spec ialists have to be female?

@WGroleau they don't have to be female to do their professional job, but as of 2024 we don't have the technology to grow a fertilised egg into a baby. The mission can save resources if each person performs multiple roles, and only women can be pregnant.

None whatsoever.
Space missions are extremely complex and take a very large amount of lead time. You can't simply drag a rocket out of storage, tank it up at the local gas station, and hit "go".
After the Columbia disaster, NASA began examining space shuttles as they reached orbit to verify that their heat shields were intact. If there had been damage (which thankfully didn't happen), the crew would cool their heels at the International Space Station while a second shuttle was stacked and launched to recover them. The rescue missions - the 3xx series - would use the shuttle and crew that were intended for the next mission, so they had a leg up on the launch requirements: a spacecraft that was already being prepared for flight, a crew that was already in training. The mission profile was very similar from rescue to rescue, so only minor updates would be needed from the planning side of things.
Nonetheless, the time between callup and launch was projected to be forty days. And this for a time-critical rescue that had been meticulously planned in advance!
If we weren't already planning to send people into space, we won't be sending anyone.

Just look at Starliner. A demonstration - not even a real mission - for a new spacecraft model carrying three people, delayed several times with significant issues during/immediately following launch, and now we can't even figure out if it's safe to use it to come back down. (+1)

If we ask for a near certain success, then this answer is correct. However, a 10% chance of sending a few people is still better than sending no one, so in such a desperate situation, to preserve the human race, we will likely try our best, especially if we stopped doing anything else and focused all our resources, sparing no expense. Such a rushed mission would have a high likelihood of blowing up at liftoff or while ascending, but there would still be at least some small chance that a few of them will make it.

@controlgroup : that was due to maximizing the chance of success. If that was no issue, we could rush it. The first circumnavigation of the planet had a death toll above 90%. People routinely risked sea voyages in the age of sail with survival chances below 50%. Today no human space mission is started with such low chances of success, but desperate times might make us consider launching them, as even a 0.01% chance of success is better than zero.

I think you misjudge the situation, when saying the possible number of rescued people is zero. (A) There are already people in the space-stations ISS and CSS (B) At least CSS surely has backup rescue vessels (near) ready to launch (C) SpaceX surely also can launch 1-2 Crew Dragons. They do launch rockets all the time (currently shut down I believe because of the Spaceship explosion, but generally they do). (D) There are also BlueOrigin (Bezos) and VirginGalactic (Branson) which might be able to do a rendevous with the ISS. (E) Russia, India probably also. Sojuz is a capable platform.

@Antares BO and VG can't reach ISS at the moment. But yeah, SpaceX, China and Russia have some ready to use rockets able to get up there in a month. No idea about ESA, India, Japan or others. That said, getting people up there and getting people to survive a year up there is a fairly different task.

@ZizyArcher: ESA and Japan (afaik) do not have own launch pads. They ship their payloads to have them started from elsewhere. The shipping is time consuming, so I think it is not an option for more launches. They can provide supplies maybe. -- You are right, getting off the planet and survive are two different tasks. But if we know how many could get off the planet, we know that the number of survivors will only be less, not more than that. That is the goal of the estimate.

@vsz: "Such a rushed mission would have a high likelihood of blowing up at liftoff or while ascending" - does it, though? I mean, are lift-off and the initial ascension really elements that are highly individual for each mission and require meticulous mission-specific planning? I agree these are very risky due to a multitude of factors and the possibility of technical failures. But is that a risk lowered by planning for a specific mission? As for maintenance e.g. of fuel tanks/conduits, presumably they are not left to rot until a concrete mission gets prepared, but continuously maintained (?)

Yeah, realistically, you might launch a couple of Dragons in a month, with luck with the timing and a lot of work to get them both ready. Add to that maybe one Soyuz out of Russia and a Mengzhou out of China... if everything aligns, you'd be doing well to get 20 people off-planet with such short notice. And that's ignoring the problem of where they live for a year before alien rescue arrives.

Given that the world is ending in 30 days all bets are off for normal space travel which gives you some writing leeway to make this work, and some opportunities for excitement:

Launch safety? Who cares everyone is dead anyway. If 1 in 50 rockets make it into orbit great!
Manufacturing quality? Doesn't need to be gold plated, just get it done, if it fails nobody is alive to complain. The 'space stations' don't need doors, windows, controls, communications... anything really which makes things easier. Just enough storage space for a years supplies and waste products for each person. Think more grain silo or large coffin than ISS. The Golgadexians can cut into them once they have brought them on board. Making working rocket engines is going to be the limiting factor.
Comfort? Don't send up pansies and you'll be ok.  Electricity for lighting, air circulation, heating, and cooling is probably all you really need. Food, water, chemical CO2 scrubbers, oxygen in tanks, dessicant to dry the air, carbon to absorb toxins, bags to poo/pee/barf in, wet wipes, tablets to watch a lot of movies on I think thats about it. If you want to understand the level of discomfort humans can withstand look into the Mercury missions.
Resourcing? What else are we going to use this stuff for? Rip anything useful out of vehicles and infrastructure, use every factory you can, don't make any new materials just burn through the stockpiles. The world probably even has enough food to last 30 days if some people check out early. Open source all the information needed, no need for patents any more!
Manufacturing speed? Round the clock shifts, no quality checks, parallel production, workers from every slightly related industry.
Survival in space? Again, if 1 in 50 last a year fantastic. If people suffocate, kill, or eat eachother ohwell. And if the rockets have genetic archives on board they don't even have to survive!
Pollution? Polluted rivers from your factory? Toxic or radioactive rocket fuels? Rocket crashed in a village? Destroyed the ground because you didn't launch from a launch pad? Pff who cares.

I think all that is only going to get you a few hundred to a few thousand survivors depending on how you write it, but along with genetics it would at least be enough to have the human race survive.
All this depends on a great deal of cooperation, or at least cooperation in some areas - panic in others. Which given humans history in disasters and wars is I think pretty realistic.
Having said all this, thirty days seems very tight, I think you could make it a lot more plausible if you relaxed it a bit to say 3 months and the Golgadexians arrive in 6 months. More time to launch, less supplies and space needed per person.
Seveneves explores a similar premise to this except they have nearly 2 years to launch, and only manage to launch 1500 people into orbit. But mankind needs to survive permanently in space, space is not safe while they are up there, and there is more time for politics - so I think they have it harder overall.
Edit:
Smaller people would help too, maybe the future is made of small Guatamalan women?
And maybe we can rip the rocket motors out of all those stupid ICBMS? That has a certain poetry to it...

I dare you calculate the amount of supplies required for a single human. Oxygen, water, food, energy, heating/cooling, biohazard recycling. For me, it hits more than 1000 tons per face, without the vessel to host all that; with vessel add an order. 10k tons per face is not feasible, considering we don't have existing projects for long-term storage in orbit. Designing all that would take enough to fail building a single escape pod.

Thank you! This is the kind of thinking I was hoping for. We're doomed. Some people will just stay doomed, but some of us will get creative.

Your comments on manufacturing speed remind me of an answer over on Space.SE about the RS-25 engine. Industrial production of new capsules wouldn't be as easy as just taking the blueprints and farming them out to a bunch of companies with no experience in the field.

@Vesper I'm not sure its all that bad is it? Going by a (sedentary person) I have roughly 0.6kg food, 2kg water, 0.5kg CO2 scrubber, 0.5kg oxygen, 1kg misc /day. So 1700kg for a year plus some shared equipment? Adjust the time in space down until it works? Or say some guy came up with an easy to build air and water regen system?

@Cadence Yeah definitely, especially with the RS-25. Isn't that the one Feynman spent ages criticising for being an overly complex unreliable design? Maybe an older engine, or the Russians or the Chinese have a less efficient but easier to build design?

@RyanM Easier to build does not mean easy to build. Using a simpler design might shave a few months off of a multi-year timeline to start production, but that won't help in a scenario like this.

@RyanM well, it's just raw materials, and you miss the systems' weight in here, which exceeds this value by a lot, also consider it's SPAAACE, aka no easy cooling, radiation shielding, complications everywhere etc etc. While yes, 1000 tons might be an overstatement, if the storage would really take several tons per year per human, so maybe several persons could be saved this way in space. But, current tech does not possess rockets to launch all that in a single package, and splitting launches (and lifting higher to avoid ejecta and atmosphere) would take longer than a month.

How many can we save?
hard-science: None
It doesn't matter how many people you can get off the Earth because when that chunk of rock slams into the Earth there won't be a habitable planet to come home to and there's no off-planet habitation anywhere that can support more than a handful of people for more than a few months at best.
BTW: I can find plenty of references that explain that the shelf life of food destined for the various space stations is one year — but I can't find any statements for how much food is stored. However, there are a great many that state food is shipped per-mission, strongly suggesting you don't have a year supply of food per-astronaut on any space station. In fact, our sister site Space Exploration asked how much storage is available, and the best guess (no official answer) is 1.5 cubic meters. That ain't a year's supply. And the problem remains available space. It's not like there's a big, empty cargo pod doing a whole lot of nothing just in case the Earth gets hit by a meteor.
science-based: A Few Hundred
In the near future...

The International Space Station has been purchased by Marriott International, which is in the process of converting it to accommodate the new and exciting Space Tourism market. With some really rapid improvements, it can host about 100 people.

And a joint venture between NASA, the ESA, the ISRO and, surprisingly, the CNSA has just opened the doors to humanity's first permanently habitable non-terrestrial location: Moon Base Alpha (scratch that... bad ju-ju with that name...) Laboratoire Lunaire Primaire (everything sounds better in French) and it can host maybe a couple of hundred people.


Locations can be stocked with enough food that humanity can survive for up to two years waiting for the dust in the terrestrial atmosphere to settle.
science-fiction: Millions
OK!

Marriott hasn't just renovated the International Space Station, it's put a half dozen brand-spanking-new Orbital Hotels into orbit and they can hold up to sixty-thousand total.

And that moon base can hold 5,000-6,000...

And the newly commissioned Марсианская среда обитания Кузнецова (I'll bet you a milkshake Google Translate slaughtered that) that can hold, with a little negotiation (say... South America), another 15,000 people.


But wait! Buy now and you'll also receive...

An impact that doesn't lead to an ELE (extinction level event). It throws up a catastrophic amount of dust... but the thousands of political leaders, scientists, and rich celebrities you got off the planet are actually irrelevant because it isn't an ELE and millions survive on the planet.

This question has exactly the same problem the former question had
And I should have voted to close both — too story-based. How many angels can dance on the head of a pin? As many as wanting. How many people can you get off the planet? As many as wanting. How many can survive the event? As many as wanting.
But if we're strictly asking about the technology available to humanity on September 18, 2024, the answer is maybe ten more than are already on the various space stations because there's nowhere to put anyone else and if you just launch capsules/shuttles into orbit they'll only have food for, what, weeks at best? And they're all dead anyway because nobody can survive long enough for the Earth to recover from the impact...
... unless narrative necessity says otherwise. Maybe the Golgadexians need to haul the mail a bit faster.

The reason I'm not a fan of "how many angels can dance on the head of a pin" questions is that there isn't a panel of judges waiting to punish any author for failing to be utterly and entirely "realistic," whatever that actually means. It wouldn't be the first time (nor the last...) that authors simply picked a number — and for good reason. Figuring this out down to the last person is way more work than it's worth... and in the end, did we create a worldbuilding rule that's independent of all stories? Yeah... kinda... maybe... but not really. If the impact didn't throw too much dust into the air, you could save people with passenger jets or by moving them to the top of mountains. Maybe my problem is that you didn't say what the consequence of impact is. If it's an ELE, then what's the point of the Golgadexians sending a 9-billion-person ship? If it's not an ELE, what's the point of the question?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

There will be thousands, if not millions of survivors, but not in space.
Why space stations will not survive
A large asteroid impact like this creates a lot of ejecta, and based on geological data available on other major asteroid impacts observed on Earth, Mars, and various moons it is apparent that most of this ejecta will radially spread out into every orbital altitude with most of the ejecta occupying Low Earth Orbits where most man made satellites exist, and the higher orbits will get less debris, but that ejecta will be more long lived meaning any station you try to push out deeper into space might be marginally more likely to survive the initial impact, but more likely to be destroyed over the course of the next year.  This degree of Kessler Syndrome will simply be unsurvivable.
This only leaves extra planetary colonization as an option... except that we are still years away from any conceivable mission that would allow people to survive a year on another planet.  SpaceX's previous timelines have proven way too optimistic with current projection not expecting the first manned mission to Mars until the 2040s or 2050s; so, you'll need to push back your start date to at least then for space to be a viable survival option.
The oceans may boil, and the air all be blown away, but nuclear bunkers are built for this
Such an asteroid will kill everyone on the Earth's surface... but there are already a number of underground bunkers around the world that are designed to survive nuclear attacks.  As such, they are also able to survive indirect super asteroid attacks that happen thousands of km away.  It is currently estimated that, there are enough Cold War era bunkers around the world to house many 10s of millions of people in the event of a global nuclear war, and most of these bunkers are designed to store between 2-30 years of provisions making them more than capable of sustaining life for the needed 1 year before relief ships arrive.  Even though many of these bunkers have not been properly maintained, a concerted effort could restore and reprovision most of them within the 30 day window, because unlike space stations, these things can be stocked up just by driving trucks between the bunker and the nearest grocery distribution centers.
The survival rate of these bunkers is debatable as the exact way in which heat will transfer around the planet is hard to estimate with limited geographic data to support what will happen.  We do know that the impact zone will blow a hole clean into the mantle ejecting rock and magma all over the world.  We also know that the vast majority of that rock and magma will land either within 2000km of the impact zone or near the impact antipode where all of the ejecta orbital paths intersect. If we assume the atmosphere is blown away then heat will be slow to propagate around the world.  Since ejecta precipitation densities outside of these 2 critical regions will be ~10,000 times less, and there is little to no air left for convection, most inland surface temperatures may not actually exceed 100C (as they get nearly all of their convection heat from steam); so, even if the Oceans boil and the surface is glassed in other parts.  Most of the Earth will only get so hot.  But even if we are way less conservative with our numbers and assume a surface temp averaging closer to 1000C, many bunkers are simply so deep that it will take years for these temperatures to equalize, at which point way more heat will be lost to radiation into space than into the ground.
Bunkers not made with these thermal conditions in mind will not survive, but many bunker will because they have underground water reservoirs they can use as heat sinks until the aliens come to save them.  Cheyanne Mountain Complex for example has a 4.5 million gallon water reservoir that the complex can exchange enough heat with to offset 2,850,869,318,080 J of themermal production which is more than enough to keep cool for many years, even at its maximum capacity of about 3000 refugees.
Then there is the impact shockwave itself.  In the case of very large impacts, my understanding is that the antipode will experience an uplift from all of the energy that does not go into the ejecta and is excess of the resonance capacity of the Earth which more or less puts a hard cap on how much a complex at a right angle to the impact can be seismically affected.  The bunker may experience a very long Earthquake, but state level nuclear bunkers use suspension systems so that they can survive the overpressure of a nearby nuclear blast.  So, the Earthquake's peak intensity should not be enough to overcome the bunker's suspension even if the whole mountain is violently shaken for over an hour as things settle out.
In summary, any bunker near ground zero or the antipode will of course be pulverized.  But if the Asteroid hits in Europe for example, there will be plenty of bunkers in the USA and Eastern Asia that will be far away enough from the impact that many of them will survive the strike. Even if a highly pessimistic 99% of all bunkers don't survive, those that remain could still contain well over 10,000 survivors.
Special thanks to Causative for challenging assumptions and helping come up with figures and considerations for this answer in comments

A potential idea, but it's unlikely a conventional bunker could survive the seismic effects of an asteroid impact of this magnitude, even if it was on the other side of the planet. Also heat dissipation would be a massive problem. The whole atmosphere is going to heat to an unlivable temperature - I calculate around 300,000 J per gram of atmosphere. (The atmosphere will probably be blown off). Also 1600 J per gram of water. Maybe a specially designed capsule with powerful cooling systems and meter-thick steel walls, buried away from any seismic faults, could survive these conditions.

While this maybe is a plausible solution and could bear a great(er) chance for survival, it is not in the scope of the question, which asks in the title "how many can we get off of the planet".

@Antares The title of the question implies that his thinking is to get people to space, yes,  but his actual question is simply "How many humans can we save?", not "How many humans can we save by sending them to space?"  I did address the issue of space not being a viable option, but chose not to go into much detail simply because there are already so many good answers explaining it.  This is more to address the part of the question that others all overlooked.

I should have added, I upvoted the answer, exactly because of that.

@causative That math does not consider how the energy will transfer.  You will not get 1600J per gram of water.  You will get billions of J of energy per gram of water where the asteroid hits turning it into high energy plasma that will be ejected into space carrying that heat away. Infact, the bigger an impact, the higher the % of ejecta will escape the planet carrying away the impact heat with it; so, the thermal consequences will be mostly localized to the impact area.  Yes, things will heat up on a global scale, but by several orders of magnitude lower than you are probably calculating.

As for the shockwave, every medium ahs a maximum decibel it can transfer because a wave can not create a negative density.  So when an asteroid strikes, it transfers this extra energy into a push that creates the impact crater, and everything beyond that point becomes a vibrational shockwave not to exceed this value. Again, this is another mechanic that will help keep the energy localized to the impact area.  Many of these bunkers are designed with significant seismic protection because they were designed to survive nearby nuclear blasts which can also achieve maximum ground harmonics.

@Nosajimiki Lots of material will indeed be ejected into space but most of it is coming back down, and whatever comes back down contributes to general heating of the surface. You won't get one order of magnitude reduction in the surface heating, let alone two. For the seismic shocks, rock can transmit a lot of energy. It's best to think of it like a glob of jello getting hit by another glob of jello. The whole Earth is going to wobble, with massive earthquakes everywhere on the planet.

@Nosajimiki A 200 km asteroid is the size that wipes out all surface life on Earth down to the microbes. If it is round and hits at 20 km/s, we're looking at 10^27 J. https://www.astronomy.com/science/ending-all-life-on-earth-would-take-a-pretty-big-object/

@causative As the saying goes, "Every complex problem has a solution which is simple, direct, plausible, and wrong."  That article is taking an energy value and spreading it out over the entire planet's surface and doing some back of the envelope math to make claims without regard for how that energy actually moves around.  That's like saying an artillery shell will heat up the armor of a tank by N degrees based on the shell's potential energy compared to the tank's surface area.   No, it heats up where it hits, and then most of that heat either splashes back or punches through with what is

left propagating outwards following a fall off pattern meaning that most of the tank is receives negligible heat. The thing about massive explosions like this is once you start to get above the 10 gigaton yield, giant explosions start to lose a lot of their destructive efficiency due to the curvature of the planet, ceiling of the atmosphere, escape velocities, and plasma deflection.  The greatest danger to life is not the impact itself, but the aftermath.

This blast will replace a significant portion of the atmosphere with greenhouse gases which will over the course of many years increase the planet's temperature by a lot. But we only need to make it for one year.

@Nosajimiki The article I linked is based on published research from researchers from Oxford and Harvard, and it said 6e26 J would be sufficient to sterilize surface life. This impactor could hit with twice that number of J. Published research is more reliable evidence than your intuitions based on a tank being hit by an artillery shell. Unlike with the tank, most of the heat energy from the asteroid will stay on the planet's surface. We have many more orders of magnitude than necessary to render the atmosphere a deadly oven, and about 1 order of magnitude more than needed to cook the oceans.

@causative That does not matter if it's all in one spot.  Volcano and asteroid impact radii greater than the height of the atmosphere have already been measured and calculated to eject most of their energy into space where most of it can not be reabsorbed, and what does come back happens over several years giving the Earth plenty of time to radiate it in a controlled fashion. Going bigger increases this inefficiency at a square-cube rate so that each cubic increase in power past this point only imparts a square increase in surface heating.

Additionally, you might be unclear about just how big and rugged some of these nuclear shelters actually are.  China’s Joint Battle Command Centre, Russia's Ural Mountain Complex, and America's Cheyenne Mountain Complex are each designed to save 10s of thousands of people from direct nuclear attacks where the surface temperatures may reach millions of degrees and shockwaves  are measured in hundreds of psi even after disapatting through the ground.

Cheyenne Mountain for example is under hundreds of meters of granite and encased in multihull spring suspension structure so that even if an apocalyptic level shockwave powerful enough to level a small mountain where to pass through it, the complex is air gapped so that only a tiny fraction of that impulse can actually pass into the structure. If just one of these bunkers survive, your aliens will have 10s of thousands of refugees to take in.

Oh in addition the the square cube thing, is the hemispherical cross section and blow off limitations.  If an explosion is powerful enough, it will blow away the entirety of the atmosphere and hydrosphere in line of sight of the impact where by all of this mass carries its heat off into space without getting to circulate with the rest of the atmosphere and oceans; so, you only get a narrow transitional zone around this ring that gets heated and not ejected.

Then all of the heat added to the Earth has be be absorbed not by the air, but by the ground.   So, instead of calculating how hot the air and oceans get, you should really be calculating how  much more hot the mantel will get.  The thing here is that the Earth has a LOT more rock than it does air or oceans; so, the ground can absorb your 1e26Jish of energy much better than your theoretical case where it all goes into the air and oceans.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The debris from the asteroid would kill everyone in LEO anyway
It really doesn't matter how many people you get into low-Earth orbit. The ISS is only about 400 km up. That's only twice the diameter of this monster asteroid! This asteroid is 8000 times more massive than the 10km asteroid that killed the dinosaurs. As soon as the asteroid hits the planet (at several tens of km/s), it will splash, and the Earth's crust and upper mantle will splash too. Low-Earth orbit will be completely filled with small rocks and cooling droplets of lava, many of which will definitely hit your space station(s) and destroy them.

Perhaps a dozen. In 30 days there might be time to prepare and launch a dozen (probably less) orbital rockets. But there would not be enough time to do anything more than pack out whatever supply craft were rapidly available for the ISS, launch as many as possible to the ISS and hope for the best.

One might consider other spacefaring nations such as Russia, India, China which have their own space ports (launch pads) and maybe also some crafts for manned missions available (especially China, because of the Tiangong/CSS). But yeah, the number of possible people to rescue will still be dissatisfying.

Yes there is some wriggle room. But 30 days is just not enough time really. Perhaps 1 or 2 from Russia and the same from China. On reflection I doubt that a dozen could be launched by the US in 30 days if it was sprung on them, probably due to lack of sufficiently cargo craft. Who ever is on ISS or Tiangong might get lucky and at a stretch a few others, perhaps.

@Slarty "probably due to lack of sufficient cargo craft" According to Wikipedia, right now there are six crew-rated ISS vehicles (two Soyuzes and four Crew Dragons), plus another three Cargo Dragons and however many Progresses have been built but not flown (they're one-use-only and typically fly every 3-4 months). Oh, and one remaining Cygnus. There might not be a dozen suitable craft on Earth!

And if it's about the long-term survival of the human species, we should not forget to send a few women as well. There are female astronauts, but very few. Also, we should hope those aliens have really good gene therapy, because a dozen people won't be enough for a breeding population without inbreeding problems.

Just send frozen sperm and ova for genetic diversity?

Sad plot twist: they end up using all of the frozen fertilized eggs from people who got IVF ... and it then turns out that when they get born, they were all now genetically predisposed to needing IVF ... which could have interesting longer term social impacts

I didn't see anybody addressing the elephant in the room.
The super advanced civilization would send instructions
They know exactly our level of space travel. They know exactly when the planet will be hit. They would have done the math.
Why send a ship (or ships) capable of saving billions if only 100 people are going to make it?
If they sent us a message with a warning, they would have also sent us a plan involving their advanced technology. So the actual answer is Everyone

Maybe we lied to them about our level of technological advancement to get around their prime directive!

@JeffUK: Yeah, uh, the, uh, evacuation fleet - right, it is, err, virtually good to go. I mean, uh, basically, err, the entire population could embark right away, like, I mean, they should, in theory. So, yes yes, please do send your advanced ships for picking up our people - yes, I understand it will take you a year to get here - no, nooo, absolutely not an issue, could equally well last two or three years up there, no worries - but if you can be here a bit earlier, like, err, within 30 days - no? Pity, ok, so, uh, see you around, looking forward to meeting all of you!

Great point! Maybe they look back through their technological archives and come up with some systems simple enough for even us backwards apes to manufacture in 30 days?

Orion
Build a huge space craft out of steel.  Dig a huge hole under it.  Stick your habitat on top with huge shock absorbers.
Take a stockpile of nukes and a method to throw them on the other side of the shield.
Set off the nukes to lift the entire structure beyond orbit.
Do this in multiple spots around the world - every nation or alliance of nations with the ability to pull off something of this magnitude.
Odds aren't great it will work.  But large industrial blocks like the USA, Europe and China could each probably build 2-3 of them.
The hard part, of course, is getting everyone aligned with helping.  Some kind of lotto system for the majority of the people on the craft might help here - a random set of people go up, and not some hand picked elites.
The thing about Orion is that the bigger the space craft, the better it works.
30 days will be extremely tight.  Your habitat(s) on top of the Orion spacecraft will be air tight, full of canned foods and water, next to no recycling, with huge supplies of oxygen (or oxygen generators).
I'd segment the habitats so leaks in one won't spread - making fancy stuff like "air locks" is secondary at this point.  You stuff the people into a can with a year's supply of light, food, water and air, plus a pit to throw waste into, and hope when you crack the can they are still alive.
Then you'd attach dozens of such cans to the top of the Orion blast shield with insane shock absorbers.
Add insulation and some kind of cooling mechanism (ice?), plus some protection for the initial launch.
Once in space, you'd stick the huge radioactive thrust-shield in the direction of the sun and hope that provided enough radiation shielding to survive the year.  And hope the aliens can find and rescue you, because you aren't rescuing yourselves.
Problems
Such an asteroid is about 10^19 kg in mass.  It will hit with roughly 10^26 J of energy, or 10^8 gigatonnes.
The Earth gets 10^16 W of energy from the sun, or 10^23 J in a year.  This is 1000 years of solar heating all in an instant.  The Earth's surface is cooked.
You will be getting high-velocity slag fired out of Earth's gravity well, as well as junk in orbit.
This solution lets you leave Earth's orbit to be safe from this problem - once outside of the immediate vicinity of Earth, Space is big, so you won't be hit by large chunks.  Smaller chunks (hot gas or sublimated pebbles) you can use the thrust shield to protect you somewhat - which means you'll want your Orion to head outward from the sun, so the shield protects both from the Earth-slag and the Sun's radiation.
Cooling is another problem.  Bringing along insane quantities of ice and using it as a heat sink is an obvious solution - if you get fancy, you might even be able to use that ice as a source of water (and oxygen) for the people on the craft.
We could rely on "dead reckoning" to manage heat levels (pray we get it right?), or hook up heat pumps to/from the ice we carry (air condition the pods).
The launch would be brutal.  Everything within dozens if not 100s of km of the launch site is dead, and massive fallout down wind.  But the Earth is sort of doomed - a bit of extra radiation isn't going to matter.
High Failure Chance
Between unrest, building something insane without having time to practice, and the scale of the construction this has a high chance of failure, especially with tight time lines.
But it has a chance.  And a few huge Orion style spacecraft could carry many 1000s of people out of Earth's gravity well.
You'll need huge quantities of steel to build the shield (steel is being used as you can get lots of it, and its strength is pretty high).  It needs to hold together until you escape Earth's gravity; the bottom of the shield will melt to slag and fall off, then repeat.  Possibly making the shield out of (insane quantities of) reinforced concrete instead might work.
The minimum size that works is on the order of 1000 tonnes.  NASA has even designed a 8000000 tonne "Super" Orion.  I'd suggest building more than one so the first launch could serve as bug-searching for the 2nd or 3rd launches.

I like it! Going old-school Footfall with this one.

My guess is the world falls to pieces on day 3. But Id watch this movie!.... Or a Footfall Movie!

@Yakk: Do you mean this Orion?? https://nasa.gov/humans-in-space/orion-spacecraft -- Do you have some links to showcase your idea? Because I don't get your concept. Why dig a hole under the spacecraft? And do you really plan "nuke blasting a kind of platform into orbit" instead of building a rocket?? Can this even work...? Or does it just tip over the "space platform" bc the nuke blast cannot be controlled that accurately? IDK, this idea seems totally Sci-Fi to me. Especially when trying something of that scale within 30 days...

@Antares No, wrong Orion. If you have truly never heard of it brace yourself.  https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/realdesigns2.php   Project Orion is about half way down this page.

Ahaaaha, lol... No. -- I heared of the atomic-explosion thrust thing before, but the bombs were considered to be detonated in space to reach as close to c as possible (which would be 0.1c or something). Not as a lift-off. Never heard about that concept. I'd say, this will not work, alone by the shock absorber thing... either you want the full push, or you don't. There is no inbetween shock absorbing possible. This will "eat up" all momentum or will be compressed after the first detonation anyway. Thanks for the link, though, interesting stuff there!

@Antares The shock absorbers are tuned so that they do absorb the first explosion and spread it over a few seconds.  As they relax, the 2nd explosion hits and they repeat.  They aren't crumple zones - they are shocks.  The design is pretty certain to work mathematically - the hard part is the engineering, and doing it in 30 days is crazy.  The point is that it is a crazy plausible thing you could try 20+ times over on Earth in 30 days and have a handful - 2-4 say - succeed, resulting in many 1000s of people surviving.

To understand Orion, it is important to remember that every part of it is bigger than you think.  These aren't your grandpa's shocks.  These are GIANT.

I actually have a friend that works on the NASA Orion project. He'd never heard of the nuke-under-a-bucket version of Orion, and was fascinated. In Footfall, they used it as a last-ditch effort to get a ship into orbit to fight the space aliens. They killed a small town getting it off the ground, but this was the fate of mankind at stake.

@RobertRapplean Those who fail to study NASA's history with the Orion keyword are doomed to not repeat it, because omg it is a stupidly crazy idea.

@RobertRapplean Never heard of it? That boggles my mind. Especially since your friend works on the current Orion. If I were there I would have a giant blueprint of the Atomic Putt-Putt on my wall.

very very few, if any if we are lucky.
If the world at large finds out the reality of the situation. IMHO nothing that is not already virtually on the pad ready to go, isn't going to happen.
The human race will collectively go insane in a thousand different ways. Getting anything manufactured, shipped maintained, anything that requires any coordination at all will be in jeopardy. When the general populace comes to realize the scope of the catastrophe, all bets are off. virtually no one will show up to work. they will go into protect / survival mode. Workers will not leave homes and family unprotected to show up for "menial" jobs. the production and infrastructure ecosystem will collapse.
Remember what happened the the logistical supply system with covid. And that was a "controlled" event...

A person is smart. People are dumb, panicky dangerous animals and you know "it."
Agent Kay: Men In Black.

Without a hope for tomorrow for an individual or at least their progeny, the human psyche will break down for 99 out of 100 people, and they will become irrational. And I would argue this phenomena will accelerate exponentially along with population density.

Next to no-one.
The biggest problem isn't even getting them off the ground, we might launch a hundred odd with a crash program, but they'll all be dead when the alien rescue craft gets here 11 months later. We don't have the orbital infrastructure to house them and their rations for most of a year and that's not a lack we can make up quickly enough to be worth trying. That same crash program is better used to get a self contained sample bank of sperm and ova into orbit plus the equipment and expertise to use it and a handful of young women of the aliens aren't up to supplying artificial wombs.
It might also be worthwhile to have the majority of the population bunker down on Earth, unless the planet is broken apart some shelters should survive until rescue.

~100 people.
SpaceX is currently launching a Falcon 9 every 3 days. They probably could do every other day, so that's 15 launches.
With a dragon capsule, it can launch 6 people to space. Probably, they could cramp 10 in there, if they had to. The bottleneck is how many dragons they can get ready within 30 days and if they can re-use them multiple times. We've seen that refurbishement is possible. So, if we assume they have 2-3 dragons ready, can build two more, re-use them once or twice, we might get up to 10 launches with dragons.
That's about ~100 people, SpaceX could get to space within 30 days.
We could cramp them all in the ISS and ship food, water and oxygen with the additional 5 launches. An expendable Falcon 9 launch can get you 20t to the ISS, so with 5 launches, there's 100tons. 1t should be enough supplies to sustain an astronaut for a year.

A side note, IIS is only intended to support 7 people, and the most it has ever had was 13.  I cannot see ~100 people squeezed into IIS.

And then the toilet broke...

In space: A few (0-99)
While we can aunch more people than a hundred, we would also require to launch and assemble a spacecraft that would remain in orbit for a year after the cataclysm, and host not only the people, but also the entirety of their life support, including food, water, oxygen, energy systems and whatever else would be required. Here, the main problem is how much mass would that spacecraft require to host per person. While the raw materials don't seem to cost much in weight (there's a comment spelling "several tons per human per year"), everything else to both contain all that water, oxygen and food, along with assembly bits and pieces required to create a self-sufficient spacecraft take a lot more.
Provided the humanity would have plans for a long-term habitat to be converted for a device with extended storage, that thing could be launched, and then supplied with several cargo ships like Progress series that are used for the ISS, thus allowing someone to survive up there for a year. There is an issue that the impact would cause the atmosphere to get superheated and thus increase drag at LEO and slightly above, but this can be compensated with pre-planning, as those cargo ships have engines that can be used to lift the orbit of fully assembled "space ark" high enough to not bother with any of the impact's after-effects.
At out current technology, we are able to design, build and launch such a system within several years; so should we, as we are now, receive a month's warning of impending doom, we would not be able to save anyone in space; perhaps the best action would be to use the ISS as existing ark, raise its orbit by a delta-V of several hundred m/s, either slowly or quickly, and then supply it with enough cargo ships to last a year with the current crew, and if there would be allowance, field there another set of people, as the current crew would definitely NOT want to leave the ISS-ark for a near-certain death on the ground. But, with those aliens around, the goverments might have ark projects of their own launched or at least developed way ahead of the announcement, either as a means to save someone if those aliens would suddenly turn hostile, or for testing of any long-term technologies in preparation to interstellar travel - you know, why not if there is somewhere to fly; thus there could be more than one ready ark, allowing more people aboard together with the supplies. Note that each ark would have a life support system of its own, as it will be designed as a space habitat.
On the ground: hundreds to thousands
There is a whole answer dedicated to underground bunkers, I won't repeat it as a whole. While those bunkers are immobile, they are loosely distributed across the surface of Earth, and are mostly built to withstand earthquakes initiated by a direct hit of a nuke. Also each of those bunkers is designed to remain autonomous for several years, supplying power, oxygen, food and water to its entire population. But, there is a potential issue of them being overheated during the first year so that all humans inside would die, as the impact is extinction-level and supplies an enormous amount of energy, way WAY more than any nuke could deliver (~1e27 J). Still, if some of the builders did account for the possibility of the atmosphere being too hot for too long, while designing and building that shelter, or they would happen to be too low under the ground for the outside heat to not reach them within a year, people in there would survive.
As an emergency means, some people might try to find shelter in "conventional" mines, bringing in some energy sources and supplies. There is a ton of mines worldwide, and while I think that they would all collapse from the shockwaves, there is a possibility for several lucky lads to not get buried alive somewhere somehow, I think that letting people into mines for emergency could help some more souls to last until salvation by aliens, although they would just count as a percent to the total populace of bunkers.
Under water: thousands already
We humans have managed to develop underwater ships that are capable of diving to about 1000 meters below the surface, with engines not requiring refuelling for more than a year, called "nuclear submarines". Of course, various subs dive to various depths, but the ballpark figure is already 400 meters deep, and is known as "operating depth", meaning a sub that deep is still able to perform all the warfare activities it can. They also have a depth called "test depth" which can be reached by a sub without it being destroyed by the water pressure, and that sub would retain the capability to surface after getting that deep (even if just once, it would still do).
Submarines have several advantages over bunkers. First, they are mobile. If some bunkers will be excluded from plans to save humanity due to being too close to the impact location, subs can move away from there before it lands.  Second, all bunkers will be hit by shockwaves spread from the impact location, as the main medium for them is the crust, and all of them are embedded into the rock, while the sumbarines could find locations where those shockwaves will not cause enough destruction - the exact set of those places varies from the impact location, yet there would be enough of them in the deep ocean, just because there is a lot of ocean. Third, a submarine is an active entity, they have sonars to detect other subs or ships and to avoid collision with the ocean bottom, this will help them to avoid most of the core breaches that would happen after the impact, and move away with the water even if it would cause a complete overturn of a single tectonic plate. I'm not sure if 1e27 J is enough to cause such great damage to the crust, but any tectonic events that would cross a bunker would cause its destruction, the sub is protected by hundreds of meters of water from all sides.
As displayed by Sleep et al., 1989 (paywalled, sourced from comments), "a 190km impactor would evaporate the photic zone, i.e. the top 200m of the oceans" together with a bunch of other effects. But, 200 meters of water turned steam is a lot less than what our oceans hold, the average depth of the Atlantic is some 4000 meters with some mountains grow to -2500m across its middle; this gives a sub a serious warranty to first not lose the ability to move and avoid hazards, and second to not get cooked by the extreme heat from the above. Thankfully, water gets less dense if heated, and has very small thermal conductivity (and very high convection), thus the ocean's deep layers are at a constant 4 degrees Celsius temperature regardless of what happens at the surface. Yes, if the Earth would be heated for several thousand years straight, the oceans would also become hotter, but a single impact of this level will not be enough to heat the entire water mass to the temperature that would cause a sub to overheat.
Of course, not every sub will survive a year, but there is about a hundred of them in operation worldwide, each having no less than 50 crew, and possibly each could host a dozen or two "passengers", considering the emergency situation. This would make the total underwater population to reach ten thousand or a tad more initially. And considering that the list of accidents with nuclear subs is decently short, a sub's survival rate could be estimated at 90%. Granted, they are all war subs, with strict orders and elevated security measures, and passengers will surely bring in a lot of hassle, but even the yearly survival rate would be only 50% (and I think it's a low estimation, yet apocalypse is apocalypse), the subs alone would save 5-6 thousand people. Building more subs is not feasible is this small timeframe, but disarming them would be possible in time to ensure that weapon malfunctions would not contribute to a sub's death, raising the survival rate potentially. (Also the freed space could be used for supplies and/or extra people)

"...there is about a hundred of them (submarines) in operation worldwide..." - note that there is 10x more in the docks, out of operation, but most of those can at least be jury-rigged to sink and surface relatively safely. Even an ancient museum U-boats could probably be fixed up just to sink below 200meters, and then resurface after a while. Even if the chance of success is low, it is better than death.
As for the mines and weaker bunkers: it might be worth considering parking tanks inside them. A tank is basically a tiny bunker on wheels, offering extra protection.

@GoingDurden the main problem is not to survive the impact, but to survive a year after the impact. Nuclear subs have an advantage of remaining submerged the whole year, while diesel subs can only submerge for a couple of days straight. And the estimated air temperature after that impact is ~400C, or greater, so what's the deal with old subs if everyone inside would perish the moment they get to the surface?

keep in mind any sub that can't travel far out to sea is going to end up thrown onto land by the tsunami the impact creates, you are talking about a wave multiple MILES high.  And you also have to worry about the shockwave transmitted through the water which could crush them like a beer can.

@John true that, both, yet nuclear subs are pretty capable of staying in deep ocean for long. Okay a tsunami several miles high, we are on the other side of a continent - no tsunami can wash over say Australia, let alone Europe. Also Mediterranean is quite a secluded place in terms of shockwave avoidance, if the impact would be somewhere in Pacific there wont be a lot of shake in Mediterranean. Re shockwaves in general - there is usually a way to avoid getting hit by direct wave thanks to continents. No sitting in fjords most likely due to tsunami, but a large deep gulf like Mexican would do.

@Vesper no there is going to be a lot of shaking everywhere, every faultline with any tension on it is going to let go, every faultline on the planet is going high magnitude quakes.  with the impact force continets don't completely stop the tsunami, the wave refract. After the chicxulub East Africa, basically as far away as you could get, saw tsunami of more than a meter just from the initial impact. At 200km there may not BE an ocean afterwards. keep in mind thats 20 times the mass of the dinosaur killer.

@John it looks like 200km impactor is still not enough to eliminate the entire ocean. Yes it will shake, but we're speaking a millitary sub after all, it's designed to get shaken (in combat), so there's still a good chance for its survival until waves cease.

Well, given our track record with global cooperation, I'd say we could probably save about seven people. And that's if we're lucky enough for Elon Musk to be one of them!
But let's break this down with a bit more optimism (and less sarcasm)
1. Current space launch capabilities: We can barely get a handful of astronauts to the ISS without it being headline news. Our existing rockets are more "space canoe" than "space ark."
2. Time crunch: 30 days? That's barely enough time for most people to decide what to binge-watch next, let alone organize a mass exodus.
3. Infrastructure: Our launch pads weren't exactly built for rush hour traffic.
4. Survival essentials: We'd need to pack food, water, and probably a few board games. Space is big, and I hear it gets boring.
5. Selection process: Imagine the committee meetings to decide who goes. It'd be like a really morbid version of "The Bachelor."
So, in conclusion, how many could we save? Probably enough to fill a small town. Let's optimistically say 10,000 to 50,000 if we really pushed it. But hey, that's enough for a decent-sized colony and only a 99.9% extinction rate!
As for the Golgadexians' offer - well, that's just typical alien behavior, isn't it? Always showing up fashionably late to the apocalypse. I guess we'll have to politely decline their generous offer and stick to our "Operation Hail Mary" plan.
At least we can take comfort in knowing that somewhere out there, a bunch of Venusians are probably having the exact same conversation. Misery loves company, even on an interplanetary scale!

I wish I could award you with a funny tag. Have my +1 and an imaginary funny award :D

Hahaha thank you! I am imaginarily honored! :D

Between the limited launch capability, and the fact that the survivors will have to sustain in space for an year, I would say about 10 - 20 people at the most.
The other answers have covered it pretty well.
But human civilization can survive. We can send a copy of our DNA databases in space and our friendly alien neighbors can clone us when they get here.
Digital cultural artifacts can also be preserved - think "Library of Congress" and "Project Guttenburg", etc.

Frame Challenge
The trick is not in how many people you can get 'up there' in 30 days but the number of TRAINED people you can round up in 30 days. Sending a million people up is useless unless they are all trained in how to survive in space. It's not as if you are sending them on a cruise, no experience necessary. It takes months of training just to learn how to eat, defecate, sleep, breathe, maneuver, and flip a switch in null gravity.
